# How do I perform these actions with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

If possible, please let me know the different variations of how to do these two things, I would much appreciate it. I have tried FOR DAYS to do these things.

edit - it is an hobby 2017 rails project i'm going to update after completing some system tests, capybara version 3.6

1. Verify this sentence exists in the email `expect(page).to etc)`:

element:

```
<b>Ok, first thing's first, please verify (at bottom).</b>
```

css selector:

```
#\:hs > div:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > b
```

full xpath

```
/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[8]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/b
```

2. Click on this link in the navbar (solved)

element:

```
<a class="pjax navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/assets/sass_hat-a30e21456cb7f6d75a0182235b1e5f72239642262f5b0bf2c8637b716207bd8a.png" alt="sass hat">
</a>
```

css selector:

```
body > header > div > div.navbar-header > a
```

full xpath

```
/html/body/header/div/div[1]/a
```

EDIT: got the second one: `click_link(href: "/")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented on your email question, which you posted separately.

For the link, Capybara documents what options can be used to find links - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L52 which states

```
# * **:link** - Find links (`<a>` elements with an href attribute)
#   * Locator: Matches the id, {Capybara.configure test_id}, or title attributes, or the string content of the link,
#     or the alt attribute of a contained img element. By default this selector requires a link to have an href attribute.
#   * Filters:
#       * :title (String) - Matches the title attribute
#       * :alt (String) - Matches the alt attribute of a contained img element
#       * :href (String, Regexp, nil, false) - Matches the normalized href of the link, if nil will find `<a>` elements with no href attribute, if false ignores href presence
#
```

So you can find by any of the things mentioned there, last of which should probably be the href entry since that will change if/when you change your routes. Either add a meaningful title and/or alt to the img in the link and then you can query based on those

```
click_link('sass hat')
```

Comment: Thomas, I appreciate that. Unfortunately, since I'm not a developer, I cannot comprehend or know how to make use of the options list. If I had the cash flow I would commission the making of a gem that paused the (selenium driver) rspec and iniated some kind of capybara console, so when you then clicked on an element in the browser, the console would query the type of interaction needed (click, fill etc), then spit out the proper code so I could pop it in my rspec for next run.

Comment: I just don't know how to apply your options in actual code.

Comment: ... got it with `expect(current_email).to have_content "Ok, first thing's first, please verify (at bottom)."`  maybe a beginner gem addon isn't necessary. still, if it existed would be handy... would have to be version dependent.  maybe call it ... Capybara Console

Comment: `click_link('sass hat')` got it, ty